# Configure iOS plist so that associated files only open in my App

Tags: ios, plist, file-association, uti

I have associated a filetype with my iOS app, which works fine. However I want the file type to be exclusive, so that other applications do not offer to 'open in' my file.

I have an app by another developer that does this, but I can't work out how it is done. I have extracted the plist for this app and I cannot see what it is doing to make this happen.

This is what I want to do :

[image]

This is what happens in my App:

[image]

This is how I have the file associations setup in my plist:

```
<key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeExtensions</key>
        <array>
            <string>abcd</string>
        </array>
        <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
        <string>My File</string>
        <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
        <string>Owner</string>
        <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
        <array>
            <string>com.myapp.abcd</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
<key>UTExportedTypeDeclarations</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>UTTypeConformsTo</key>
        <array>
            <string>com.myapp.abcd</string>
        </array>
        <key>UTTypeDescription</key>
        <string>My File</string>
        <key>UTTypeIconFile</key>
        <string>icon</string>
        <key>UTTypeIdentifier</key>
        <string>com.myapp.abcd</string>
        <key>UTTypeTagSpecification</key>
        <dict>
            <key>public.filename-extension</key>
            <array>
                <string>abcd</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</array>
```

What am I missing?? Does anyone know how to enable this functionality?

Thanks

Duncan

Comment: Are you sure you're dealing with the exact same filetype and/or MIME-type? It could just be that there's something custom or different about the file that the other app opens which only has itself (and Mail.app) registered for it.